# How to edit a binary SeLinux policy file?

Tags: linux, android, selinux, non-root-user

It appears root access is irrelevant on my device as everything is managed by SeLinux (the root user basically can’t execute anything).

The problem is I can’t just create my new polices. I need to keep the existing ones in order to keep the fingerprint scanner and the lte module firmwares happy.

Almost every settings seem to be in `sepolicy`. But this is a binary file:

```
% file sepolicy
sepolicy: SE Linux policy v30 MLS 8 symbols 7 ocons
```

I just found `apol` from setools to view it’s content but not to dump or edit it.

What’s the expected way to edit such file’s type?

Comment: Example CentOS 8 : `$ file sepolicy` → → `sepolicy: Python script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines`

Comment: @KnudLarsen in my case, that’s a binary file generated by vendor through the standard SELinux format not a python script. It exists. I need to keep most of what it contains (the phone crash with SELinux disabled). I need a way to read first without learning the binary format details (I mean I don’t want to do it inside an hex editor but something more friendly).

Comment: There are tools like `sepolicy-inject` which you can use to edit a selinux database. But you won't be able to edit that file on android, because it's part of the initramfs boot image. You can of course rebuild the boot image and reflash your device. The process is quite complicated and involves factory-resetting your device.

Comment: build permissive kernel from source, otherwise you will face a chiggen-egg-dilemma

Comment: @mosvy flashing the boot image is how I can modify the file. But I can’t modify `/system` only the initrd.

Comment: @alecxs the kernel is statically linked with closed source binary drivers. I can’t rebuild it (or I can provided I do accept getting a phone which can no longer be used for receiving phone calls or performing mobile Internet). But I found where to write in the boot image so I only change the initrd without the kernel.

Comment: You can of course modify the `/system` if you're able to remount it rw (But the sepolicy file is not stored on the `/system` partitition on any device I know of) On my phone, I have a ssh server which starts from the initrd image BEFORE the init process drops all capabilities and is no longer able to remount it.

Comment: @user2284570 If the kernel is linked with closed source binary drivers, then REPORT IT. It's a GPL violation.

Comment: @mosvy `/system` is linked with a hash partition using the `dm-verity` from the Linux’s kernel (which means the device is read only at run time). Any physical block change which isn’t cryptographically validated with the hash along with the manufacturer keys results in an invalid block read. I can change the manufacturer public key provided I can write to the matching block device on Internal storage which is the point of my question.

Comment: @mosvy for the lte pretty much every manufacturer is in that case. That’s why you can never send music over a phone call (at least through the dedicated hardware without sip) even with plain Linux/asterisk replacing the android rom.

Comment: the closed source binaries are included in source code package, no problem. you just need to patch the kernel source code and compile with `CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM=y` and `CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y`

Comment: @alecxs they aren’t included (and that’s I mean by you can’t on most phones) but in my case, the problem is in userland.

Comment: if they aren't included, how can twrp be build? twrp needs permissive kernel, too

Comment: @alecxs twrp is about recovery not the main image.

Comment: .. and recovery is living in boot ramdisk and share the same kernel, that's why for a successful build twrp comes with precomplied own permissive kernel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106041/discussion-between-user2284570-and-alecxs).

Comment: Use Magisk's `supolicy` tool to inject a fully permissive context to existing `sepolicy`. See [How to manually root a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217157/218526)